# Groß- / Kleinschreibung von Fremdwörtern

Tags: noun, spelling

Was würdet Ihr als "best practice" für die Groß- und Kleinschreibung von Fremdwörtern sehen? Beispiele: "[best practice](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_practise)" ;-), "[quick freeze](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Freeze)", "[squeeze-out](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_Out)"? Macht es einen Unterschied, ob die Begriffe "eingedeutscht" sind?

Ich bevorzuge eigentlich die komplette Kleinschreibung, weil damit die Fremdwort-Eigenschaft besser hervortritt. **Edit**: Der Duden gibt die Großschreibung des ersten Begriffs ([Regel 40](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/fremdwoerter#K40)) einschließlich substantivischer Bestandteile vor, außer für adverbielle Reihungen; also "Best Practice"; "Quick Freeze". Die doppelte Großschreibung erscheint mir aber etwas "unnatürlich", insbesondere entspricht sie (AFAIK) nicht dem, was in der Fremdsprache selber üblich ist (die englische Wikipedia scheint für "Best Practice" zwischen Groß- und Kleinschreibung zu schwanken, das dort verlinkte businessdictionary.com hat das Lemma komplett in Kleinschreibung).

Zudem frage ich mich, ob und wie man die zitierte [Regel 40](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/fremdwoerter#K40) sauber von der [Regel 39](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/fremdwoerter#K39), die eine Übernahme der fremdsprachigen Schreibweise zulässt, abgrenzen kann?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Substantive, die nicht angeglichene Fremdwörter (z. B. fachsprachliche Ausdrücke) sind,  werden groß geschrieben.

Beispiele:

> Milieu, Jalousie, Moiré, Breakdance, Philosophie

Ebenfalls groß geschrieben werden reine "Zitatwörter", die entweder sehr fachspezifisch sind oder kulturelle Einrichtungen, Ereignisse u. Ä. des Herkunftslandes bezeichnen.

> Carnegie Hall, New Deal, High Church.

Begriffe, die im Deutschen weniger gebräuchlich sind, sollte man entweder mit Anführungszeichen oder typografisch kenntlich machen; in diesem Fall bleibt die Kleinschreibung der Substantive erhalten:

> Wir wurden zu einem »business lunch« eingeladen.
>   Es ist ein für die englische *detective novel*  typisches Handlungsmuster.

(Quelle: Duden "Richtiges und gutes Deutsch",  5. Auflage, 2001)

---

Im Deutschen gibt es übrigens zwei verwandte Wortarten, die aber streng genommen nicht dasselbe bedeuten:

- **Fremdwort**: ein aus einer fremden Sprache übernommenes Wort, das sich nicht bzw. nicht grundlegend der aufnehmenden Sprache angepasst hat
- **Lehnwort**: ein aus einer fremden Sprache aufgenommenes Wort, das hinsichtlich Lautung, Schreibung und Abwandlung an die aufnehmende Sprache angepasst ist (*"eingedeutscht"*, um den Begriff der Frage zu verwenden)

Comment: ah - prima, danke, habe gleich den Titel der Frage entsprechend korrigiert (es geht mir ja um Lehnwörter, nicht Fremdwörter - ich nehme jedenfalls an, dass meine Beispiele eher unter Lehnwörter fallen). Die Groß-/Kleinschreibung muss ich noch ein wenig "setzen lassen"...

Comment: @tohuwabohu Es tut mir schrecklich leid, aber ich habe die Begriffe unten selbst verwechselt. ist inzwischen bereinigt. Ich erlaube mir, deine Frage wieder zu ändern.

Comment: :) kein Problem - ich hatte es selber nicht mehr nachgeprüft - Danke für Deine Hinweise!

Answer (score 2):

Ich plädiere für Großschreibung von Substantiven, egal, aus welcher Sprache sie kommen - obwohl die Beispiele aus Regel 39 dem zu widersprechen scheinen.

Stell Dir einfach vor, es wären deutsche Komposita mit Bindestrich dazwischen, so wie Lachs-Ersatz. Auch dann schreibst Du beide Substantive groß.

Es kommt wohl darauf an, wie die Wörter verwendet werden: Als Fremdwort - dann deutsche Schreibweise, oder als Zitat einer Fremdsprache - dann Originalschreibweise und Anführungszeichen oder Kursivschrift.

Comment: Ich denke die Unterscheidung von Groß- und Kleinschreibung wird in ein paar Jahrzehnten unbedeutend. http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=video&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CFAQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DKyLqUf4cdwc&ei=HZcETpjGOMf3sga88cikDA&usg=AFQjCNHPk6xYGcVySzm8VyKEDUCMWLo6jQ&sig2=YOuqV78oSErpq4-vvVjtyw